# Do I need a visa to enter the UK as the non-EEA spouse of an EU citizen?

Tags: united-kingdom, indian-citizens, eu-spouses

I am an Indian citizen married to a Romanian woman. We have a two-month-old child. I have been living in Romania for the last 6 and a half months. I have a Temporary Residence Permit from Romanian authorities. Now we would like to relocate to London together to find work and settle. My wife and son don't need a visa to enter and remain in the United Kingdom. Can I enter the UK with my residence permit or do I need some kind of visa? If I do need a visa, which visa do I need and how do I apply?

Answer (score 7):

You should apply for an [EEA family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/overview).

When you apply, be careful to include the fact that you and your wife have a child together.  There is apparently a strong tendency for applications to be refused because the entry clearance officer (ECO) suspects a marriage of convenience.

The UK's own guidance to ECOs explicitly says that couples who have children together must not be suspected of having a marriage of convenience, so this is your best strategy to avoid a refusal.

Once you arrive in the UK, you will need to apply for a [residence card](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card) as evidence of your continued right to live there.

Comment: (+1) I understand the OP wants to find a job for himself while his wife would not be working. It's not impossible but it makes things more complicated than doing it the other way around (i.e. when the EU citizen works and sponsor economically non-active relatives). It might be useful to add some details on that to the answer.

Comment: @Gala I'm not entirely clear on how that works, so if you want to edit the answer, or add your own, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Good luck with this. There are stories of people with 10 year marriages and 3 kids being refused as a marriage of convenience... The HO largely just ignores the law.

Comment: @ゼーロ the government's own policy states that a marriage of convenience is not to be suspected if there are children of the marriage.

Comment: @phoog Sure, but they don't actually follow that policy. Just yesterday the Home Secretary had a contempt of court case brought against her.

Comment: @ゼーロ that case had nothing to do with freedom of movement or even EU law.  There was a case in which a couple with a child were denied an EEA family permit; it was [decided in 2012](https://www.freemovement.org.uk/new-case-law-on-marriages/), and the current guidance dates from 2013, so while I can't confirm it, I suspect that the guidance changed then as a result of that case.  In any event, I don't think the UK has dug in its heels since then on any case in which there was a child or evidence of cohabitation.